# multiple divs, some left, some right, all vertically aligned with CSS

Tags: css

What would be the best way, given any number of elements in a container, to align some elements to the left and some to the right while centering both left and right content vertically?

For example, given this markup:

```
    <div class="action">
        <div class="message">This is our message</div>
        <div class="comment">Comments for the message</div>
        <div class="person">John Doe</div>
        <div class="date">01/18/2013</div>
        <div class="time">12:35 PM</div>
    </div>
```

Can the message and comment be left aligned in the action container while the person, date and time are right aligned with both left and right content vertically centered?  Can this be done without new markup and with any content length for each element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some CSS would do the trick.  Have the containing div position: relative, and float the children div's either left or right.  Also center-align the text.

```
.container{
    position: relative;
}

.left{
    float: left;   
    width: 50%;
    background-color: Silver;
    text-align: center;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: Yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/EMLBJ/1/)

Comment: But if there are multiple left divs and multiple right divs, the right divs will fall to be inline with the last left div.  Also, this doesn't vertically center either side.  Right?

Comment: To make sure I understand, you want both columns to be the same height (equal to the tallest column), and the shorter column to be vertically centered?

Comment: Correct.  Regardless of the length of the content in any of the divs or how many divs are on either side, the shorter column should be vertically centered to the content of the longer column and both columns should be vertically centered to the container.  Thanks.

Comment: Would you be against adding a left and right container through javascript?  The initial html wouldn't change, I would wrap a div around all .left and float them.  Same with the .right.  Then calculate the tallest and and vertically center the shorter.  Updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/EMLBJ/5/) a little

Comment: Changing the markup, either directly or with Javascript is my fallback, but I figured I'd check and see if someone smarter than me could do it with pure CSS.  Maybe it's not possible.  Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

With a *minimal* change to existing markup (introduction of two div tags, one for each column), this becomes rather trivial if you use [Munawwar's flex-helper](https://github.com/Munawwar/flex-helper).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hbox flex">
    <div class="left vbox main-center">
        <div class="message">
            <p>This is our message.</p>
            <p>It spans many lines.</p>
            <p>Or rather, paragraphs.</p>
            <p>Additional waffle.</p>
            <p>Syrup, bacon, a banana.</p>
            <p>Tall glass of milk.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">Comments for the message.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right vbox main-center">
        <div class="person">John Doe</div>
        <div class="date">01/18/2013</div>
        <div class="time">12:35 PM</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Example-specific CSS*/
/*left column*/
.left {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: Silver;
    text-align: center;
}
/*right column*/
.right {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: Yellow;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Minimal use of Munawwar's flex-helper*/
/* https://github.com/Munawwar/flex-helper */
/*Stack child items vertically*/
.vbox {
    display: flex;

    /*Align children vetically*/
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;

    /*Prevent extending beyond boundaries*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*Stack child items horizontally*/
.hbox {
    display: flex;

    /*Align children horizontally*/
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: flex-start;

    /*Wrap items to next line on main-axis*/
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    /*Prevent extending beyond boundaries*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*Stretch item along parent's main-axis*/
.flex {
    flex: 1;
}
/*Stack child items to the main-axis center*/
.main-center {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Leif_AMO/psuq7mbt/3/)

No waffles were harmed in the production of this answer, though some may have been eaten.